# Opencsv - How to get values separated by commas outside double quotes only while also ignoring double quotes?

Tags: java, opencsv

My csv values are separated as follows:

> number, "This is a string, that has comma", foo, bar

This is my csv reader:

```
CsvToBean<MyObject> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<MyObject>(reader)
                    .withType(MyObject.class)
                    .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                    .withSeparator(',')
                    .withIgnoreQuotations(true)
                    .withSkipLines(1)
                    .build();
```

which actually results in these values:

> number
>
> This is a string
>
> that has comma
>
> foo
>
> bar

What I really want is:

> number
>
> This is a string, that has comma
>
> foo
>
> bar

I tried to look through other questions from the website, but it seems they are not similar to my issue. So how can I separate values by **commas** outside **double quotes** only and also ignore the double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I only need to remove the ignore quotations line and it works fine:

```
CsvToBean<MyObject> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<MyObject>(reader)
                    .withType(MyObject.class)
                    .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
                    .withSeparator(',')
                    //.withIgnoreQuotations(true)
                    .withSkipLines(1)
                    .build();
```